# Displaying the submitted javascriptMVC form Data in another Div

Tags: jquery, forms, javascriptmvc

I am using javascriptMVC and the issue I have is this.

I have a form with almost all the types of Input, and when I submit on the form I want the data displayed in another Div next to it. I don't want to use a Database. I want to do it only using files created when generated using MVC framework

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
$.post("post_your_data_to_this_site.php", $("#idOfYourForm").serialize(), function(data) {
  // add result of post_your_data_to_this_site.php into div
  $('#yourSubDivId').html(data);
});
```

If this is not working for you please explain why.

Regards